# Using a variable as continuous and categorical

Tags: categorical-data, references, modeling, binning

I have an IV and a DV which are both scale scores. I have categorized the IV and dependent variables based on previous studies. I wanted to do this to calculate the prevalence of DV and IV. I also used an independent sample t-test to compare the means between the categorized IV and continuous DV. Finally, I did a correlation and hierarchical regression with continuous scores of both IV and DV. I did this because of  my research questions

1. Is there a higher prevalence of DV in people with and without IV-Cross tabs
2. Does IV have a significant effect on the DV-Independent sample t-test?
3. The association and relationship between IV and DV-correlation, Regression

Are there any articles that support the use of a variable as continuous and categorical to answer the research questions?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! It seems that you’re chopping up a continuum and sticking chunks into buckets/bins, a practice that [is discouraged.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/592246/247274)

Comment: Thanks for your response. So how do I calculate prevalence and compare them? This study is the first to be done in my target population, a particular group of workers, so that prevalence can be an easy way to explain to government officials that these workers are severely affected. How do we calculate the prevalence for continuous scale scores? The scale authors themselves are giving interpretation of scores- my primary question is can we switch between categorical and continuous scores of a same variable to answer research question.