# Changing the regression problem to a classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, classification, continuous-data

I'd like to do the classification on a crime data around the country. However, what I have for the label is the crime coefficient which is from 0 to 1. I'd like to make up some interval like 0~0.3 as low crime rate, 0.3~0.5 medium etc. And then use it in the xgboost or random forest model to do the classification. Is there anything I need to pay attention to before the classification? For example, do I have to check the label whether it is normally distributed? What if the data is skewed? What would you do if you are working on this project?

Comment: Why do you want to throw away information?

Comment: This would be the worst possible way to analyze the data, throwing away a tremendous amount of information and introducing a huge amount of arbitrariness into the result.  You need to just be careful in choosing  a distribution for crime rate, and possibly use Bayesian borrowing of information in the small area estimation sense.

Comment: Note that [random forests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest) and [gradient boosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting) work perfectly well for regression.

Answer (score 1):

In this case my suggestion would be to predict the actual numeric crime rate and then apply the threshold to arrive at low/medium crime rate.

In order to come up with different thresholds, you can create intervals on predicted crime rate by following some great suggestions to cluster 1D [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40454/determine-different-clusters-of-1d-data-from-database). If you prefer simplicity rather than finding natural separations, you can hard code some quartiles (e.g. 1 quartile is low, 2/3 is medium 4 is high).